# How to create another user (students and teachers) table in django

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and have some confusion right now. I want to build something where teachers table will be in a onetomany relationship with students table. But I could not create another student table. Any advice or resource,please?

Comment: What do mean, could not create another student table? Are you unable to create a Student model, are you unsure how to use ForeignKeys or are you running into errors?

Comment: @Stevy there is a default User table in django which I'm currently using and I'll call it teacher table. I just want to create another table called student table.Hope you undestood :)

Comment: Students will login with their credentials coming from that table

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what your exact question is but to create tables/models where a Teacher has one or more Students you can create your models like this:

```py
from django.db import models
import uuid 


class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='teachers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teacher'


class Student(models.Model):
    student_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'student'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer.I know I didnt explained it very well,my apologies. But I just want another table where I can keep student's username,email,hashed passwords like in the default user model. That's it

Answer (score 1):

Just try using Foreign keys.  One to Many relationships does not exist in Django.  You can choose Foreign keys which can help you to achieve the problem.

Teacher's Model File

```
class TeacherModel(model.Models):
    ...
    student_id = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name='students_id')
    ...
```